# What would cause Eclipse to struggle switching to the correct file and line number when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have been using Eclipse to debug Java applications for years, and it was working fine just a week or two ago. Today it's acting very strange. I set a break point and it triggers fine but the file and line number are not changing (quickly) as I step into or over lines.

This is a pretty complex issue I am debugging as Java Action Bean code is being called from JSP pages by sometimes many threads but it's never been a problem before. It's like Eclipse is doing something in the background and is very busy as it will eventually update the debug file and line to match the current stack trace.

What would cause extreme delays switching to the debug location in the editor?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in the current version of Eclipse without additional plug-ins? If yes, what do you have configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Debug_?

Comment: My version is 2019-09 R (4.13.0) and the issue is not repeating itself this morning. I am pretty sure I inadvertently fixed it yesterday evening after getting the new version of Google Sync straightened out. It had been 'syncing' all day long somehow using the systems resources without showing anything in the task manager.

Comment: I've actually seen this symptom from time to time in the last year or so.  When it happens, it highlights the top stack entry, but clearly is not showing it. When this happens, I double-click the stack entry and it displays the correct file and line at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entire problem was caused by Google Sync secretly updating itself and putting a limit on my mail folder size on disk without even telling me. It was 'syncing' all day which I did notice but the CPU/memory loads seemed normal.

I did update Eclipse at one point to latest but that didn't seem to fix the problem.